# JPA CriteriaBuilder - how to add parameters with different dynamic types to criteria? Getting ambiguous call error

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api, jpa-2.1

I'm new to JPA and got stuck with a rather straight forward use case. All I want is to add some conditions to my criteria based on certain filter user passes to my application. User passes the information to application using key, value pairs and we'll decode it to see what type each parameter is.

Eg:

1) key=id and value=20. We'll interpret it as search by id=20, where id is integer

2) key=name and value='test'. We'll interpret it as search by name='test', where name is string

This is achieved by a method like this

```
public <T> T getSearchValue(Object inputValue) {
   if (condition) {
      return (T) inputValue.toString();
   } else {
      return (T) Integer.parseInt(inputValue.toString);
   }
}
```

I was thinking that I could easily add the condition using criteria builder. Something like this

```
cb.equal(getSearchKey(), getSearchValue(inputValue));
cb.gt(getSearchKey(), getSearchValue(inputValue));
```

Here `cb.equal` works fine. But `cb.gt` or any other operation like `lessThan`, `like` etc. are all giving compilation error that there are 2 method matches and hence ambiguous

First method is `gt(Expression<? extends Number>, Expression<? extends Number>)`
and second one is `gt(Expression<? extends Number>, Number)`

So how do I resolve this and make sure it can resolve to Number as the second parameter for example? Problem here is I don't know the type in advance as it is added based on what key user want to search with. Is it possible to dynamically cast to a class somehow or is there any other better approach here?

Answer (score 2):

Idea is to supply the restrictions to the where clause of the "SQL statement".

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE key=value
```

Lots of people like to write JPQL queries similar to SQL because it is easier to understand when reading. Nevertheless, there are some advantages about using this Criteria API (dynamic, less error prone, less attention for security, easier to refactor).

The first step is getzing the `CriteriaBuilder` and then, creating a `CriteriaQuery` with it. Afterwards, you could go on to define from which class you want to build the `Root` and use this to get the columns. Joins could also follow.

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<YourClass> cq = cb.createQuery(YourClass.class);
Root<YourClass>  root = cq.from(YourClass.class);
```

As a next step, you want to define the where clause with its restrictions (Predicates). As in a normal SQL statement, there could be only one where. If you have multiple restrictions, they have to be combined with `criteriaBuilder.and()`.

There are several ways of applying the whole process. I have one way how I do this (and some others might do it like this as well). Usually, I create a `List` with all restrictions I want to use and create an array out of this which gets then combined with the `cb.and()`.

```
List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("key1"), "value1"));
predicates.add(cb.gt(root.get("key2"), 100));

cq.select(root).where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));
```

Following, a whole example for such a DAO method.

```
public List<Foo>(String state, int size, String column, String value) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Foo> cq = cb.createQuery(Foo.class);
    Root<Foo>  root = cq.from(Foo.class);

    List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(Foo_.bla), state));
    predicates.add(cb.gt(root.get(Foo_.blub), size));
    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(column), value));

    cq.select(root).where(cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()])));

    return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

For getting the column names (or singular attributes), I used `hibernate-jpamodelgen`. Have a look for this plugin which generates classes with underscores automatically (e.g. `Foo_`) which makes it more typesafe when using column names.

Update: If you do not know the names of the columns for your restrictions in the where clause beforehand, it is simple to adjust it (see third restriction above).